# Permisos de Usuario - Jsf - PrimeFaces

Tags: java, primefaces

Hola Tengo el siguiente caso,
Necesito habilitar o deshabilitar componentes de **PrimeFaces** teniendo en cuenta los permisos asignados en la Base de Datos, la mayor parte de ejemplos son por paginas en este caso requiero controlar los componentes por ejemplo:

Tengo una tabla permisos en la base de datos asociado a un usuario:

**Usuario:** Pedro

**Pantalla:** Usuarios

**Componente:** BotonGuardar

**Permiso:** Si / No

Si el usuario tiene permiso = Si, disabled="false"

```
<p:commandButton value="Disabled" id="BotonGuardar" disabled="false" />
```

Si permiso = No, disabled="true"

```
<p:commandButton value="Disabled" id="BotonGuardar" disabled="true" />
```

La idea es controlar este comportamiento desde el **Bean** para cada usuario.
Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puede usar Expression Language de la siguiente manera, asumiendo que el permiso sea almacenado en una variable boolean en el managed bean de nombre permiso con sus respectivos getter and setter y que el facelet apunta a un managed bean de nombre bean:

Vista

```
<p:commandButton value="Disabled" id="BotonGuardar" disabled="#{bean.permiso}" />
```

ManagedBean

```
 @ManagedBean
 public class Bean{
      private boolean permiso;

       public boolean getPermiso(){
            return permiso;
       }
       public void setPermiso(boolean permiso){
           this.permiso = permiso;
       } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Una manera elegante de hacerlo es definir un método genérico que se ocupe de acceder a BD en base a la variable `component` y al usuario:

```
<p:commandButton value="Disabled" id="BotonGuardar" disabled="#{seguridad.debeDeshabilitarse(component.id)}" />
```

`component` es una variable que se carga de manera automática con la información del componente (doy por hecho que usas JSF 2).

Así, te podrías crear una clase Seguridad que recupere de sesión o donde tengas almacenado el usuario y se conecte a BD para comprobar si el componente debe mostrarse o no.

```
@ManagedBean
public class Seguridad implements Serializable{
    public Boolean debeDeshabilitarse(String componentId){
        MiDAO dao = getDao();
        Usuario usuario = getUsuario();
        return dao.debeDeshabilitarse(componentId, usuario);
    }
}
```

Y en BD tendrías una tabla con clave primaria (Componente, Usuario) que te facilitara la información.

De esta manera podrías reutilizar la función por toda la aplicación de una manera cómoda e igual en todos los casos.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es validar si debe estar habilitado o no un botón lo que debes hacer es crear un método en el bean que devuelva true o false y luego asignarlo en la etiqueta, ej:

```
//  XHTML
<p:commandButton value="Disabled" id="BotonGuardar" 
    disabled="#{miBean.validacion()}" // Debe devolver true o false

//  Bean
...
    public Boolean validacion(){
      return true;
    }
...
```

Espero mi respuesta te haya ayudado, saludos.